# Passing an object name to an event

Tags: c#, xaml

I am writing a c# function that populates several comboboxes with items.  However, I can't seem to pass the object/field name to the function and could really do with a hand.

The first variable is the query string and the second is the XAML object

```
    SetupComboBoxes(
        "SELECT Machine FROM Machines GROUP BY Machine ORDER BY Machine",
        txtMachine);
```

The code it calls was going to be something like this:

```
private void SetupComboBoxes(string strQuery, object objFieldName)
{
    MySqlCommand cmd;
    MySqlDataReader dr;

    cmd = new MySqlCommand(strQuery, con);
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        objFieldName.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `object` does not have a property called `Items`. If you need to work with a `ComboBox` inside your method you need to tell the compiler that the parameter is a `ComboBox`. Otherwise you could pass any object at all into `SetupComboBoxes` and it would crash when you tried to access a non-existant `Items` property.

Comment: np. let me make than an answer so we can close out this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you declared your method:

```
private void SetupComboBoxes(string strQuery, object objFieldName)
```

You've told the compiler that the second parameter is an `object`. `object` does not have a property called `Items`, which you are trying to use later on. The compiler isn't going to let you do that, because as far as you've told it, you could pass *any* kind of object into your method. Most of those won't have an `Items` method, and your program would crash. The compiler is enforcing *type safety* on your code. Other so-called "dynamic" languages may allow you do to this, and would only do the type safety checks at run-time, but C# is not one of those languages.

If you need to work with a `ComboBox` inside your method you need to tell the compiler that the parameter is a `ComboBox`:

```
private void SetupComboBoxes(string strQuery, ComboBox objFieldName)
```

That will allow you to access all of the properties of a `ComboBox` in the method, and will also prevent your from accidentally trying to use that method on something that's not a `ComboBox`.